# How to configure jenkins to build ant project

Tags: java, ant, jenkins

It was relatively easy to set up Jenkins to run Java Maven projects.

Now I'am trying to migrate a Java project that was built in Luntbuild using Apache ANT 1.7.1. with not so much success.

The Java code check out successfully but I get the following error when the build starts.

```
FATAL: Unable to find build script at /"repoAddress"/.../build.xml
```

Any tips to what I obviously done wrong?

Comment: Can you post your build configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to tell without more info.
I would verify that the ant module points to the right build.xml file, and double check (browse the workspace) that it's where I expect it to be.

Comment: I checked out the repository again and double checked everything and lo and behold it was a simple typo thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

If you did specify a local module directory (not sure of english translation) in "source code management" be sure to include it in the path for your build.xml
Furthermore there is no need to give an absolute path. A path relative to your checkout directory (maybe modified by a local module directory) is sufficient.

local module directory/checkout root/ ... /build.xml

or

.. / .. / build.xml

Comment: Thanks i will try to use an relative path instead.

Answer (score 0):

In manage jenkins change the workspace location to the place where your project is. And rerun the build.
By default the workspace would be pointing to `HOME>/.jenkins`. So it is trying to find your project there.